# Tailwind css apply order

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want to know tailwind css apply order. Or it can be issue of general css order.

However, when I put 2 classes, `bg-gray-50` and `bg-gray-500`, `bg-gray-50` class is applied only. It doesn't matter for order of two classes.
So, `bg-gray-50 bg-gray-500` and `bg-gray-500 bg-gray-50` has same effect.
Always `bg-gray-50 class` is applied only.

Why does it work and how can I apply `bg-gray-500` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in file css core of tailwind which they defind all class of tailwind, they place class `bg-gray-50` before `bg-gray-500`.So it compile the first class and ignore later class. You can imagine their order:

```
// tailwind.css
.bg-gray-50 { background-color: #E9E6E6 }
.bg-gray-500 { background-color: #DCD7D7 }
```

if you want to apply `bg-gray-500`, defind `backgroundColor` by `style` property which is more priority `style={{backgroundColor: '#DCD7D7'}}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any other solution? I am using tailwind css in React, and I want to customize style by passing classnames.

Comment: you can add `!important` to class you define in file `tailwind.config.js`

Comment: @Yerycs One thing you can do is to conditionally add only one of the classes. Or you could set inline css style if you want to override tailwind class.

Comment: This approach sooo defeats the purpose of TW!  ... It's one of the key issues with this framewark actually.  Just because something happens to be defined after in the resulting css! How can we control that?!

Answer (score 1):

just add Important modifier `!bg-gray-500`

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#important-modifier